# Angular2 D3 Labels and Text are not displaying in Firefox, Works well in Chrome

Tags: d3.js, angular, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

Please find https://plnkr.co/edit/XsuAuOFasQnJPK5uhfc1?p=preview for the same issue.`enter code here`

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question directly instead of just linking to an external resource. Providing a Plunker is just great but it should be possible to see what the question is about without opening external resources. Code in links is also not searchable which makes the question harder to discover for others interested in similar issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `clippath` to `clipPath` in your template.

Comment: This makes display the text ;-) See https://plnkr.co/edit/KqGjkhpXFfKEbn4xm8pG?p=preview

Comment: That Worked Thaks :)